# i want to save the result of one command in a file

Tags: linux

I am using cppcheck tool to analyze source code.

At the shell prompt in gcc compiler, I have given the command as follows

```
$ cppcheck abc.cpp
```

The output is

```
checking abc.cpp...   
(error) Possible null pointer dereference: <var> - otherwise it is redundant to check if   <var> is null at line 100    
segmentation fault
```

I want this output to be saved in a file, so I have given the command as follows

```
$ cppcheck abc.cpp 2> abc.txt
```

But the contents of abc.txt file is as follows

```
checking abc.cpp...
```

It is only saving the first line, the main error part is missing in abc.txt file.

Which command should I use to get all the output lines in a file? The manual of cppcheck tool is [here](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Drop the `2` from your command and just use `>` as the redirect operator.

By using `2>` you are redirecting the error stream (STDERR) to a file; what it sounds like you want is the regular output stream (STDOUT).

```
cppcheck abc.cpp > abc.txt
```

If you want *both* streams to go to your file, you can connect 2 (the error stream) to 1 (the standard output stream) them like this:

```
cppcheck abc.cpp > abc.txt 2>&1
```

Or use the [shortcut syntax lain suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12514/i-want-to-save-the-result-of-one-command-in-a-file/12515#12515) to just grab everything.

Comment: Nice one. I'd never seen `2>` before. Learn something new every day here. :)

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to redirect stdout as well as stderr to your file

```
cppcheck abc.cpp  &>abc.txt
```

Comment: @lain this answer is exactly backwards. If you read the question you'll see he is catching just stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: @Caleb: As you can see I realised that and edited it but the command is the same

Comment: @lain ... and I changed my vote :) I know the solution worked but the explanation was misleading to somebody who clearly doesn't have a grasp on io redirection issues.

Answer (score 3):

[Caleb is right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12514/i-want-to-save-the-result-of-one-command-in-a-file/12516#12516) about the use of > but you can also use the `tee` command if you would like to see the logs at the same time as you save then to a file.

```
cppcheck abc.cpp | tee my.file.txt
```

And it should work with the 2>&1 as well.

```
cppcheck abc.cpp 2>&1 | tee my.file.txt
```

Comment: Why the downvote? don't like the tee command?

Comment: Downvote wasn't me, but it's canceled out now :) Good additional suggestion. I might suggest writing it up with this users exact command though so they see better how your suggestion fits into the big picture.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote it as it's not _wrong_, but probably because using tee only for redirection is superfluous. tee only really helps if you have more commands piped after it.

Comment: @hometoast: You use it to "debug" a long pipe chain. So you later can look at the output from the different stages? Example "find / | tee a.txt | grep -v bin | tee b.txt" and then compare a.txt and b.txt to see what grep -v removed in the middle? Or what did you mean?

Comment: @Johan: ah. I see what you mean now. Clever.

Comment: @hometoast: tee is a funny little thing :)